# Connect to SQL Server database with Azure App Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, database-connection, connection-string

I'm deploying an website for my company and it was, originally, hosted in an on-premise server. Now I want to upload it to the cloud **(Azure App Service)** but I'm having some issues concerning the database's connection string.

While the website was being developed, I used to connect to the SQL Server Database with user authentication via PHP:

```
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>"database_name", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
$connCRM = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Now that it's in the process of deployment, I want to connect to the database with a db user and password:

```
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>"database_name", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");
$connCRM = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Considering I'm not connected to the VPN (the website is not located locally anymore), it seems like it can't find my server, even though I'm accessing it through TS (in the destination server).

Already tried to authenticate in SSMS with this user and password and it's working.

**Error message:** Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 11001 [code] => 11001 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9 [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 11001 [code] => 11001 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )

Answer (score 0):

Your App Service is hosted in Azure, so it is indide Azure network, and you are trying to connect to a database server inside your organization network(since you indicate it is on-prem), so unless you configure your org firewall to allow inbound connection on the port in which db server is listening, connection would not be established. If your SQL Server is using default port, you need to allow inbound on port 1433.

**Update**: As an alternate, if solution must not require changes to firewall, then [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) is suitable one.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it is an alternative. However, we want to maintain our firewall as safe as possible. In order to do that, I was considering creating a private endpoint connectivity directly to the server via VNET, but it demands a higher App Service plan, do you think it's worth the price?

Comment: May be you can compare that with the pricing if you had used [Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections), that is another alternative that doesn't require changes to your firewall.

Comment: It turned out that I used hybrid connections, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great, updated my answer, you could `accept` it now.